# How can I query FTs with a specified account name using RPC call on NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

Could anyone can help me slove this proble

---

m. I want to quey FTs with specify account_name. I find the doc「https://docs.near.org/zh-CN/tutorials/fts/simple-fts%E3%80%8D, and query by rpc call, from the pic, there are two questions:
no matter what account_id「in args_base64」  i pass, it seems that return result still the same. So i want to know the mean of params.account_id and args_base64.account_id
Can i get more infomation about result.result, such as Fungible Tokens name、synboml、decimals
[image]

i want to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your base64 string (`eyJhY2NvdW50X21kIjogImIudGVzdG51dCJ9`) corresponds to `{"account_md": "b.testnut"}` (see the typo there, it should be `.testnet` instead of `.testnut`.

> Can i get more infomation about result.result, such as Fungible Tokens name、synboml、decimals.

Yes, you need to call `ft_metadata` function with `{}` arguments (base64 `e30=`).